# Searching for various numbers from a given list inside a table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a simple question that i could not find any reference to and i would appreciate any help.
i have a list of user_ids sent from the client to the server - for example - (1,2,3,4)
and i want to search in a table of groups how many time each group got the those users inside.
the groups table's columns are : group_id,group_name,user_id

and i want the result to show each group name and the number of times number from the searched list's numbers appear inside.

i also want to show if it doesn't as 0.

example:

```
groupName     NumOfCustomersFromTheSentListThatAreAttachedToTheGroup
  A                   0
  B                   3
```

i was thinking something like:
select group_id,COUNT(userID) FROM userByGroup where userID in (1,2,3,4) group by group_id;

but then i have 2 problems:

1. i don't see that ones with no appearance (because of the WHERE)
2. i get a record for each appearance and i want a record for each group

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a separate groups table [Groups] and a separate table that maps the users to the groups [UserGroups].  If that's the case, you should be able to get away with this:

```
select group_id, (select COUNT(user_id) from [UserGroups] where [UserGroups].group_id = [Groups].group_id and [UserGroups].user_id in (1,2,3,4)) NumberOfUsers from [Groups]
```

If not, then you'd have to subquery the original table like so:

```
select group_id, (select COUNT(user_id) from [Groups] g2 where g2.group_id = [Groups].group_id and g2.user_id in (1,2,3,4)) NumberOfUsers from [Groups]
```